# Find the maximum number of honest leaders

Tags: mathematics

In a room of 100 leaders, at least 1 leader is honest; and in every pair, at least one leader is dishonest. Find the maximum number of honest leaders, if every leader is either honest or dishonest.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Please do not use random tags - make sure the tags you use are applicable to the question.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like the question could be a little more clear, but if I'm understanding it right the answer is:

> Just that one. If there were more, you would create a possible pair of two leaders such that not every pair contains at least one dishonest leader.